# PhoneGap application: Upload a file from javascript code to JSP web page on Tomcat

Tags: android, jsp, cordova, file-upload

Is it possible to upload a file ,i.e json file, from javascript/HTML code to JSP web service? I read lot of examples that uploads files to PHP service but I am more familiar with JSP coding. I am building an Android mobile application using PhoneGap and jQuery/JavaScript technology. I would like to upload a text file or JSON file from the mobile application to a JSP web service. If a JSP web service is able to receive the uploaded file, how to write to code for both client side and server side to save the uploaded file to a local folder?

Thanks

Comment: Use FileTransfer function provided by PhoneGap and make the url parameter pointing to the jsp file. The jsp file can be created by following the tutorial here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_file_uploading.htm